# How to trap server error in getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to set error handling in my getJSON calls.

This is my calling code:

```
 try
 {
     $.getJSON(uri)
       .done(function (data) {    
            //do some thing with the result
     }).error(errorHandler());
 }
 catch (err)
 {
   alert(err);
 }
function errorHandler(page) {
    return function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(page); // it works
    };
}
```

and my web api code is:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<InformedCommon.Time> GetTimes(string licenseKey, string camIndex, string date, string id, string guid)
{       
    throw new Exception("hi");
}
```

The error handler code is not called.

In the view element console I got:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I then found this link:
http://www.paulbill.com/97/how-to-handle-errors-using-getjson-jquery

So, I re-coded it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('ERROR: ', data);
    }
});
```

But still this error is not caught.

So:
what is this best way to handle an error from the server call?

Comment: The ajax error function will be called if its a Http related error. Which is not your case. You are just throwing a program exception. But you can try this link [link](https://2leggedspider.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/handling-exceptions-using-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc/). Maybe it helps

Comment: @Pumpkin Hi, looks interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch errors from getJSON, use .fail, not error

```
$.getJSON(uri)
       .done(function (data) {    
            //do some thing with the result
     }).fail(function(){
    //handle your Error here
});
```

But if you throw a Exception on your server script, it isnt transfered to the client - just the 500 internal server error.

I think you should catch the exception on the server side and send it in an JSON to the Client and then process it in the .done  function.

Comment: After all that so simple!

Comment: Yes, re: catch server error. It was just in case the server was down

Comment: server won't return anything if it is down, request will fail anyway though